# Discord JS Send Datas such images

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm searching how to send data in form of images, like the MEE6 Bot, who send, for exmeple, the Rank, and the level status like image and a 'loadbar' in it.

I'm searching from yesterday but i find only things like "send directly images" or "send image like message" or send an image with a text in the message", but nothing for send datas like image such MEE6.

How can i do that? there exists libraries/packages that permit to do something similar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, you'd like your discord bot to send an image? You would do that by creating an embed and defining the image property with the URL to the image you'd like to send.

Here is the embed you'd need to create:

```
message.channel.send({embed = {
  "image": {
    "url": "http://link/to/image.png"
  }
}}).catch(console.error);
```